# How does flurry count downloads?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, download, flurry

good afternoon dear flurry

I have a question, I would like to know
how does flurry count downloads of mobile apps ?
Does flurry see reinstallation on the same device as a new event? 
for example, the user has installed the application. deleted it and then installed it again. How many installations does flurry count 1 or 2 ?

Comment: hi Nusha, this is not the platform to ask questions like that. This platform is for asking questions like "why does my code not work?" or "can you help me with my code"

Answer (score 0):

Flurry only counts the first installation, it does not count re-installations as separate installations. For the broader question, Flurry counts the "First Launch" of the app, rather than the install itself.